# Error during Installation tar.bz2

Tags: software-installation, make

I am trying to install a tar.bz2 package which a Mediatek Bluetooth Driver.

The package can be downloaded from here http://www.mediatek.com/AmazonS3/Downloads/linux/MT7612U_DPO_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.1_20140718.tar.bz2

I am getting some errors plz help.

```
shirshendu@WORKSTATION-7A:~/Downloads/DPO$ sudo make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/tools'
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7662u
chipset = mt7632u
chipset = mt7612u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPSetInformation’:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:2207:21: warning: unused variable ‘Value’ [-Wunused-variable]
              UINT32 Value;
                     ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPQueryInformation’:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:3881:45: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘RtmpDrvRateGet’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      newRateGetAntenna(HTPhyMode.field.MCS),&RateValue);
                                             ^
In file included from /home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/include/rt_config.h:62:0,
                 from /home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:29:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/include/rt_os_util.h:510:6: note: expected ‘UINT32 * {aka unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘ULONG * {aka long unsigned int *}’
 VOID RtmpDrvRateGet(
      ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:3895:45: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘RtmpDrvRateGet’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      newRateGetAntenna(HTPhyMode.field.MCS),&RateValue);
                                             ^
In file included from /home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/include/rt_config.h:62:0,
                 from /home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:29:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/include/rt_os_util.h:510:6: note: expected ‘UINT32 * {aka unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘ULONG * {aka long unsigned int *}’
 VOID RtmpDrvRateGet(
      ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlRF_mt’:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4896:11: warning: unused variable ‘value’ [-Wunused-variable]
  CHAR    *value;
           ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5492:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 intf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, _
                                                                     ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5492:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 , size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                     ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_ioctl_giwrate’:
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7534:25: warning: unused variable ‘rate_count’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int rate_index = 0, rate_count = 0;
                         ^
/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7534:9: warning: unused variable ‘rate_index’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int rate_index = 0, rate_count = 0;
         ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/shirshendu/Downloads/DPO/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic'
Makefile:390: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

After following your instructions and after recompiling i got this
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13596239/

System details as requested by you:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13596284/

Comment: I have now added the link as per your request

Comment: I have edited the questions and added the details as you requested.

Comment: Even I solved few, I get stuck with some network functions, it seems that this driver need a patch to work with 4.2 as it was prepared for 3.x . I lack knowledge to solve it. May be you can find an already patched one on web.